# How to change the database local to be in a cloud (Django)

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-database

I wrote a project in django framework and I use the local DataBase SQLite, and I now want to upload it to the cloud so other people who work with me can access DataBase i.e. when I create a user then that user will exist with my co-workers.

Maybe someone has a guide on how to do this without modifying the DataBase so that I do not have to modify the rest of the code?

Comment: What if you share your sqlite file? sqlite is for local db so in my opinion if more than one uses are working in the project you can use a different  database i.e postgres. Your models are not changing a lot  so the transition is not hard to be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the answer,
what you should do **is Connect Django and MongoDB Using Djongo**

you can read from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-and-django)

### I RECOMMEND TO FOLLOW MY SETPS.

1. go to monogodb site -> [clickHere](https://www.mongodb.com/)  and create free account.
2. create new cluster
3. then you will reverse to this page if no in the left side press **DataBase** under DEPLOYMENT and then you get. [image]
4. press on Connect buttom [image]
5. choose "Connect your application" and then choose python and the last version

after all this you will have this link:
for example!!!

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<atlas cluster>/<myFirstDatabase>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

copy this link and do the next setps:

- go back to your terminal and install this package: `pip install djongo`
- and open settings.py
- change your DATEBASE to like this:

> ```
> DATABASES = {
>         'default': {
>             'ENGINE': 'djongo',
>             'NAME': 'your-db-name',
>             'CLIENT': {
>                 'host': 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<atlascluster>/<myFirstDatabase>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
>             }  
>         }
> }
> ```

- in 'host' paste the link you copy from monogodb site.
- in 'NAME' write your name of the database.

Now that we have the Django project (and app), you can create the collections in MongoDB using the commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app-name>

python manage.py migrate
```

if you get error like '**django.db.utils.databaseerror'**
what you should to do is:
It deletes all the files that are in the migrations folder that are in the apps you have created and after that run again the command above.